# integral of $e^{-\imath x}$ from $a$ to $\infty$ and characteristic functions

Tags: complex-integration, characteristic-functions

In the following result: $$\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(u) \left[\int_a^{\infty} e^{-i u x}dx\right] du = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{ \pi} \int_0^{\infty} \Re\left[\frac{e^{-i u a} \Phi(u)}{i u}\right] du$$
$\Phi(u)$ is a characteristic function and $a$ is a constant. I think $$\int_a^{\infty} e^{-i u x}dx$$ is divergent, because $\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-\imath t} $ does not exist.

Question is, how does above result exist then? Even if I suppose that $\lim_{t \to \infty} e^{-\imath t} =0 $, I cannot get to the RHS.

Comment: I think this uses the language of distributions. First identify the LHS as a Fourier-transform of a characteristic function (which is essentially a sinus cardinalis - the thing on the right side).

Comment: Can you please explain a little more or give a reference. Thanks.

Comment: It holds that
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(u)~\mathrm e^{-\mathrm i u x}\,\mathrm du = \hat \Phi(x)
$$ in the sense of distributions (where $\hat\Phi$ denotes the Fourier-transform of $\Phi$). And there are tables e.g. on Wikipedia, where it is explained, how the Fouriertransform of a characteristic function looks like.

Comment: We are not calculating FT or Inverse FT. I think Inverse FT is being further integrated from $a$ to $\infty$ (the order intedration has been changed on the LHS). How do we explain conv of the integral in the brackets?

Comment: Could it be helpful to first replace the upper value of the $x$-integral by $T>0$ and take the limit $T→∞$ in the end?

Comment: @Urgje: I have already mentioned this limit in the question, and that is one part which I do not understand; $\lim_{T \to \infty} e^{-i T} = \lim_{T \to \infty} (\cos(-T) + i \sin(-T))$, which I think does not exist.

Comment: It depends. Before you take the limit the u-integral must be done first. In case the characteristic function is that of a set outside [a,∞) then your expression actually vanishers by a theorem of Lebesgue.